# Flattening Streams produced from multiple JDBC ResultSets, to prevent loading everything in memory

Tags: scala, jdbc, stream, resultset, lazy-evaluation

I am given `List[String]`, that I need to group in chunks. For each chunk, I need to run a query (JDBC) that returns a `List[String]` as a result.

What I'm trying to get to is:

- All the results from the different chunks concatenated in one flat list
- The final flat list to be a **non-strict collection** (so as not to load the whole ResultSet in memory)

This is what I've done:

Producing a `Stream` from a `ResultSet`, given a `List[String]` (this is the chunk):

```
def resultOfChunk(chunk: List[String])(statement: Statement): Stream[String] = {
 //..
  val resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)
  new Iterator[String] {
    def hasNext = resultSet.next()
    def next() = resultSet.getString(1)
  }.toStream
}
```

Producing the final list:

```
val initialList: List[String] = //.. 

val connection = //..
val statement = connection.createStatement
val streams = for {
  chunk <- initialList.grouped(10)
  stream = resultOfChunk(chunk)(statement)
} yield stream

val finalList = streams.flatten

statement.close()
connection.close()
```

(Variable names are intended to prove the concept).

It appears to work, but I'm a bit nervous about:

1. producing an `Iterator[Stream]` with a for-comprehension. Is this
   something people do?
2. flattening said `Iterator[Stream]`  (can I assume they do not get evaluated during
   the flattening?).
3. is there any way I can use the final List **after** I close the connection and statement? 
   Say, if I need to do operations that last a long time and do not want to keep the connection open during this, what are my options?
4. does this code actually prevent loading the whole DB ResultSet into memory at once (which was my actual goal) ?

Comment: @sschaef: why is emphasizing things discouraged/undone? Did it not highlight the main ideas, making the question easier to follow? Apologies if not, that was my only intention.

Comment: If you need to highlight the important parts of your question then your question is probably not clear enough / too long. Furthermore these bold/italics things are hard to read and others must not share your opinion about which parts are the important ones. Text formatting should be used to give a text a form not to underlay its meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll reply one by one:

1. Sure, why not. You might want to consider flattening in the for-comprehension directly for readability.

   ```
   val finalList = for {
     chunk  <- initialList.grouped(10)
     result <- resultOfChunk(chunk)(statement)
   } yield result
   ```
2. See above for flattening. Yes you can assume they will not get evaluated.
3. The `Iterator` cannot be re-used (assuming `initialList.grouped(10)` gives you an iterator). But you can use a `Stream` instead of an `Iterator` and then, yes you can, but:

   - *you* will have to make sure it is fully evaluated before you close the connection
   - this *will* store all the data in memory
4. Yes it does

Based on what I've seen, I'd recommend you the following:

```
val finalList = for {
  chunk  <- initialList.grouped(10).toStream
  result <- resultOfChunk(chunk)(statement)
} yield result
```

This will give you a `Stream[String]` that is evaluated as needed (when accessed in sequence). Once it is fully evaluated you may close the database connection and still use it.

Comment: Awesome! What if I needed to perform a mapping on "chunk" before passing it to resultOfChunk ? How would I do that? Calling toStream on both "chunk" and "mappedChunk":   chunk <- initialList.grouped(10).toStream; mappedChunk = chunk.map(...).toStream; result <- resultOfChunk(mappedChunk)(statement).  Does that look right?

Comment: Yes. You can also map only in the `yield` statement (`yield f(result)`). Depends only on what is more readable for you.

Comment: Wonderful! I'm sorry to abuse this thread -  I can't help but ask: if I used connection pooling (with some PooledDataSource), and WITHIN the for-comprehension: 1) obtained connection by dataSource.getConnection and 2) passed that to resultOfChunk instead a statement, then where would I close that connection? (I don't think I can, because I won't be able to access the Streams later on). But if it's not possible to close it, then does it even make sense to use connection pooling ? (I'm thinking that connections might not be released back to the pool without closing). Thanks so much, kind sir.

Comment: @teo You will need *the* connection you use for queries open until your stream is fully evaluated (or you do not need any additional elements). The difficulty when retrieving the connection in the for loop, is not really being able to have it escape the scope. You might want to consider two for loops. Again: It is up to your program logic to ensure to close the connection only when the streams are fully evaluated.